# VBA Documents.Open Name = always "Document1"

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to open a word .docm file via a string with Documents.Open. It works and opens the file but inside the WordHandle.Documents(x).Name it's always "Document1". Also the opened documents are named "Document1"

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub FileOpen(ByVal fileName As String)
    If Not gb_WordObjSet Then
           Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not FileExists(fileName) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With gh_WordObject
        .Documents.Open fileName:=fileName, OpenAndRepair:=True

        With .ActiveWindow.View
            .Type = 3
            .ShowAll = True
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

fileName e.g. = "C:\temp\20150702161254.docm"

gh_WordObject is initialized like this

```
Set gh_WordObject = CreateObject("Application.Word")
```

Comment: Could we see the rest of your code?

Comment: How do you initialize `gh_WordObjSet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same behaviour that you would see if you manually opened the document within Word, using the "Open and Repair option". To see this, go to the select your document in the File Open dialog, then click the drop down arrow next to Open and choose "Open and Repair". This will create a new document based on the original.

To open the document normally, remove the OpenAndRepair parameter:

```
gh_WordObject.Documents.Open FileName:=s_DokFileName
```

or set it to False:

```
gh_WordObject.Documents.Open FileName:=s_DokFileName, OpenAndRepair:=False
```

Comment: Thanks its working! Sometimes but very rarely generated word object are corrupted. OpenAndRepair solved the problem. Do you know common sources why such corruption could happen? I'd have to debug A LOT of code =/.

Comment: @Megamind - If you're only accessing the document via the Word Object model (rather than directly manipulating the File), then it's unlikely that the corruption is caused by anything that you're doing in your code. If you see frequent corruption when using a particular template, then it could suggest that the template is corrupted.

Comment: @Megamind If you want to be able to handle the situations where there is a corrupted document, I'd check whether this causes the Open method to return an error. If it does, you could include some error handling to try opening the document with the OpenAndRepair option when that error occurs.